# How to individually select data from multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm sure that it can be done and possibly exported to Access instead but I was just wondering if anyone had any suggestions for a problem that I've come across.

I've got an excel file full of baseball statistics batting and pitching. Each year gets a different worksheet or 2015 batting and 2015 pitching. This has been done for multiple years.

I would like to make a totals worksheet which consists of the totals for every player but only showing on one row.

- Each year some players no longer play on the team and each year some new players appear. Rather than go in individually and try to do it by hand that would literally take forever I would like some way of searching for say "John Smith" throughout all of the tabs and tally up his totals for batting and pitching.
- Each worksheet has headers such as At Bats, Hits, Doubles, Triples, HR, RBI, ETC.

This is more for leisure and not something that needs to be accomplished I'd just like to do it if anyone has any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: There is the jist of it right there. I started from 1901 and currently working on 1915.

Comment: @pnuts ....... This is essentially what I'm doing but only for one team. Thanks for that reference as I was wondering if anyone had constructed something like this (on a smaller level) other than Baseball Reference, ESPN, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about copying and pasting every players name into a separate worksheet, then remove duplicates. After that, you could do a sumif based on the players name. The first one would take a couple of minutes but after that, you could scroll them down using absolute references.

Comment: Anthony thanks for your response I've considered something like this but think there's got to be a way of achieving this without doing all of that.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using tables, rather than excel basic cheets, which will make the following easier.

The gist of my solution is to use Index(Match()) nested in sum(), or what ever else you want to test, average, standard deviation etc. It's similar, but more robust than vlookup, as if the structure of your table changes, the formula will edit accordingly. Without more detailed information on the structure of your file it would be along the lines of:

```
=SUM(INDEX(batting2015[PA],MATCH(outputtable[@[Name]], batting2015[Name])),INDEX(batting2014[PA],MATCH(outputtable[@[Name]], batting2014[Name])),... etc)
```

The first step is to understand the output of INDEX(MATCH()). [INDEX()](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) will return the reference value from a range. [MATCH()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx) looks through a vector of values for a specific value. By using MATCH() to find your players, and pairing it with INDEX() to return their result (batting average, at base etc.), you can then sum these values from subsequent sheets. 
The form of the table would be the same as all the others, with players as different records vertically, and stats as different fields horizontally. The benefit here is you only need to make one formula per field, then it will auto copy down if you build it in a new Excel table object.
Worth noting is that players who may have similar first names will could be incorrectly matched unless you specify the match to be 'Exact' by setting the match type argument in MATCH to 0 MATCH(lookup_value,lookup_array, MATCH_TYPE).

Also, seeing as you have tables, I'm assuming you are deliberately using structured referencing. If no, [this is a quick primer](https://support.office.com/en-AU/article/Using-structured-references-with-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e).

Comment: Hi Dave I could be missing something here and probably am. I've gone to my blank totals worksheet and under the header PA I've inserted the following code:   =SUM(INDEX(1901 batting[PA],MATCH(Name[@[Name]], 1901 batting[Name])),INDEX(1901 batting[PA],MATCH(outputtable[@[Name]], 1901 batting[Name])))              This results in an error highlighting the "(1901 batting[PA]," in the first part of the code.

Comment: I was actually using a pseudo code, and assuming firstly that your sheets each have a table object on them (they look like it from the screen shot), and then assuming that the table name was the same as the sheet names you described. If this is new to you check the link I put at the end of my answer. You can also check your table names via Formulas > Name Manager. Using tables and structured referencing really speeds up this kind of project if it's set up right to start with.